# Where can I get pycharm-debug.egg for Idea?

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm, remote-debugging

I can't find `pycharm-debug.egg` in IntelliJ Idea (2016.2) installation directory, where can I get it?

Comment: See also: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/remote-debugging.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is distributed as part of [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download) in its `debug-eggs` directory. On MacOS, right click `PyCharm.app`, Hit Show Package Content and find it in `Contents/debug-eggs/`

[image]

---

The file **was** also available in [JetBrains/intellij-community](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) github repository:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/162.1628/python/testData/debug/pycharm-debug.egg

Change the branch to match your version appropriately. One has to pay attention to versions since if version of the egg doesn't match the version of Idea

```
Warning: wrong debugger version. Use pycharm-debugger.egg from PyCharm installation folder.
```

may be printed or the debugger may even refuse connection.

Comment: File doesn't appear to exist in that repo at that location anymore. :/

Answer (score 4):

I just contacted JetBrains and was informed that their documentation is out of date and that it's now located in `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/<product_version>/python`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Ubuntu Snap, it's in

```
/snap/pycharm-professional/current/debug-eggs
```

(via https://askubuntu.com/a/979238/902312).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only supported in the Professional edition.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)